# Looping with an XML animation file?

Tags: android

I created an animation in an xml file. 
I apply it on a textview like this :

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.exit_about); 
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART); 
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); 
v.findViewById(R.id.global_about).startAnimation(anim); // v is my view
```

This runs once even if I set a repeat count. 
Any idea ?

Comment: I found solution in another answer. Works for me. Cheers! https://stackoverflow.com/a/4844448/6049708

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is odd, I had the same problem, and then I found out about the setRepeatCount and setRepeatMode functions, and implemented them, and then they worked for me fine.

here's my code:

```
new AnimationUtils();

Animation controller = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.flasher);
controller.setRepeatCount(-1);
controller.setRepeatMode(2);
sectionText.startAnimation(controller);
```

Maybe try reversing the order of your `setRepeatCount` and `setRepeatMode` functions? Maybe there is something weird going on with your view?

Comment: Changing the order nor replacing constants by "-1, 2" did solve it for me. I add the anim to ImageView and TextView programmatically from Android 3.2 to 4.x .

Answer (score 1):

```
    Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
    anim.setDuration(50); //You can manage the time
    anim.setStartOffset(20);
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    Yuor_textview.startAnimation(anim);
```