# Rotation animation, slow it down

Tags: android, animation

I need to slow down an rotate animation over an imageview: it begin faster, then it should "decelerate" until end of animation (then rotation stop). I've write this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<rotate
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="30"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

then add listener to animation:

```
Animation rotate = AnimationUtils
            .loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.rotate);
    ImageView logo = (ImageView) SplashScreen.activity
            .findViewById(R.id.logo);


    rotate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,
                    LoginActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(intent);

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            if(animation.getRepeatCount() == 5) {
                animation.setDuration(200);
            } else if (animation.getRepeatCount() == 10) {
                Log.i("ANIM", "10");
                animation.setDuration(5000);
            } else if (animation.getRepeatCount() == 15) {
                animation.setDuration(800);
            } else if (animation.getRepeatCount() == 20) {
                animation.setDuration(1600);
            } else if (animation.getRepeatCount() == 25) {
                animation.setDuration(2000);
            } 

        }

    });

    logo.setAnimation(rotate);
    logo.startAnimation(rotate);
```

but animation has always the same velocity (code never go into onAnimationRepeat). What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
```

in your animation xml file.
 check this link for other interpolators http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html
also add

```
android:repeatCount="1"
```

because the default is 0.

Comment: zealdeveloper told me the same thing, and it doesn't work the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<rotate
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="30"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Change interpolator cycle_interpolator to decelerate_interpolator so that you get an effect which is faster at beginning and gradually slows down.

Comment: i've try also with that interpolator, but it doesn't work. I can't understand why onAnimationRepeat is never called

Comment: can you try setting repeatCount to infinite

Comment: i don't need to repeat to infinite animation

Comment: also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480652/android-animation-does-not-repeat