# Make two Views visible simultaneously in Android

Tags: java, android, view

I have this code in my Android application:

```
private void showMyViews() {

    mAnimation.cancel();
    mAnimation.reset();
    mAnimateionView.clearAnimation();
    mAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mOtherViewToHide.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mFirstViewToShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mSecondViewToShow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

But sometimes mSecondViewToShow appears a little bit before mFirstViewToShow. How could I easily force these Views to appear at the same time?

Some of the code is:

```
public class mFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, com.squareup.picasso.Callback {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mFragment, null);
    mFirstViewToShow = (RelativeLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.mFirstViewToShow);
    mSecondViewToShow = (RelativeLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.mSecondViewToShow);

    ...
    ...
    ...

    if (isConnected()) {

        animateMagnifier();
        updateUserLocation();

    } else {

    }

}
private void animateMagnifier() {

    Thread mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            AppLog.Log(TAG, "ver si la lupa sirve");

            if (getActivity() != null) {

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        mAnimationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        animeMagnifier = AnimationUtils
                                .loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                                        R.anim.translate_center_amim);
                        mAnimationView.startAnimation(animeMagnifier);

                        // Code use to repeat the animation
                        // See
                        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480652/android-animation-does-not-repeat

                        animeMagnifier
                                .setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationStart(
                                            Animation animation) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationRepeat(
                                            Animation animation) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(
                                            Animation animation) {
                                        animeMagnifier = AnimationUtils
                                                .loadAnimation(
                                                        getActivity(),
                                                        R.anim.translate_center_amim);
                                        animeMagnifier
                                                .setAnimationListener(this);
                                        mAnimationView
                                                .startAnimation(animeMagnifier);
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    });
    mThread.start();
    try {
        mThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void updateUserLocation() {

    ...
    ...
    ...
    sendDataToServer();

}

private void sendDataToServer() {

    ...
    ...
    ...
    findPerson();

}

private void findPerson() {

    new BackGroundTaskForFindPerson().execute();

}

private class BackGroundTaskForFindMatch extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {


            findPeopleResponse = mServices.makeHttpRequest(
                    Constant.find_people, Constant.methodeName,
                    findPeopleValuePairList);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ...
            ...

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            if (success) {

                if (mFindPeople.getErrNum() == 2) {

                    // no one found

                    mFirstViewToShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mSecondViewToShow.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    messageTextView.setText(R.string.no_one_near);


                } else if (mFindPeople.getErrNum == 3) {
                    ...
                } else {

                    ....

                }
            } else {

                messageTextView.setText(R.string.no_one_new);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ....
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

}
```

Comment: As drawing happens on UI thread (the same thread you're working on right now) it is not possible for this code to behave like you explained. Do you change visibility of those views somewhere else in code?

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev Yes I do, depending on different behaviours I change the Views to "VISIBLE" or "GONE". Is there any solution with "Threads"? Or is that too complicated? Thanks!

Comment: No, there's only main thread which is involved. Could you post all other code which updates visibility? I think I have a clue why this might happen, but I need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: I tried to write a "short version" of my code (it's very long) Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Set them to `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE` that way they will be attached to your layout but hidden.

At the moment they must be added to your view hierarchy before they are revealed, that's probably what's causing your delay.

Comment: Thank you! The delay is still there!

Comment: @JuanCarlosPiñeros that's the spirit!