# Android animation "blink" when repeat

Tags: android, android-animation

In my application I have this animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"/>

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:startOffset="4000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9"/>

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:startOffset="4400"
        android:fromXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="0.9"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="5800"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"/>

</set>
```

Generally it shows image, make "press" gesture and hide it. What I want is run this animation in infinite loop. Setting parameter `repeatCount` doesn't work. Only way I found is to start animation again in animation listener.

```
final Animation pointerAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pointer);

pointerAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(final Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {
        pointerView.startAnimation(pointerAnim);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {}
});

pointerView.startAnimation(pointerAnim);
```

But here comes **my problem**. Between end and new start animation, the image "blink" (appeared and disappeared in short moment) and I don't know how to prevent this. Using `fillAfter` doesn't work. Also setting appropriate visibility in listener doesn't work. Note that target API is 10.

I'll be glad for any advice

Comment: Have you checked this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480652/android-animation-does-not-repeat

Comment: Yes, I checked it but I didn't find anything helpful for me. I cannot merge all my animations into just one. And also trying number of possible combinations of flags `fillBefore`, `fillAfter` and `fillEnabled` didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was surprisingly tricky, but here's an answer that seems to work and avoid the blinking. Break the animation up into two parts and set two animation listeners so that when each of them finish, they trigger the other one to start. It looks as follows:

pointer_fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:shareInterpolator="true">

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:startOffset="2000"
    android:fromAlpha="0"
    android:toAlpha="1"/>

<scale
    android:duration="400"
    android:startOffset="4000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:toYScale="0.9"/>
</set>
```

pointer_fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<scale
    android:duration="400"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:fromXScale="0.9"
    android:fromYScale="0.9"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1"/>

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:startOffset="1400"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0"/>
</set>
```

Then the code:

```
    final Animation pointerFadeInAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pointer_fade_in);
    final Animation pointerFadeOutAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.pointer_fade_out);

    pointerFadeInAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(final Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {
            pointerView.startAnimation(pointerFadeOutAnim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {}


    });
    pointerFadeOutAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            pointerView.startAnimation(pointerFadeInAnim);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
    });

    pointerView.startAnimation(pointerFadeInAnim);
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: I had the same problem with an app I am working on and this is the solution that worked for me too.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works like charm for mentioned case. But I have same problem with another animation, where I have two `translate` animations so I cannot break this AnimationSet into two separated anims because the animated view jumps back to the original position after first part of animation.

Comment: Interesting, can you share the code for the translate animations?

Comment: When I was writing answer for you, I got an idea. I broke my animation like `alpha` and `translate` + `translate` + `alpha` instead of `alpha` + `translate` and `translate` + `alpha` and it started look how I wanted. My last question is WHY??? Why dividing into two animations helped?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try combining both `repeatMode` and `repeatCount` attributes like in the following example

```
<scale
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="2000" 
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    />
```

Hope it has helped

Comment: But I want to repeat whole animation, not only some parts (like `scale` for example). Setting these attributes for whole animation in XML or in code also doesn't work.

Comment: How about trying to do it programatically like so : 
    anim.reset();  // reset initialization state
    anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
    anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a workaround that won't be applicable in your case, but would it be possible to offset the entiere animation, so that it starts at 3000 ? (Thus, when alpha=1.0)

(Well, after some thought, I'm pretty sure you can't do that, because the alpha transition should be the first when the object first appears on screen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9"/>

    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:startOffset="1400"
        android:fromXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="0.9"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="2800"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"/>

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:startOffset="5800"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"/>


</set>
```

Comment: You wrote it in brackets. I didn't get your idea but simple "copy & paste" doesn't work. Even whole animation didn't appear, only "blink" stayed.