# Android Animation repeat -> image animation set

Tags: android, android-animation

i am trying to scale an image, rotate it, rotate it backwards and then scale it to its origninal size. 
This is allready working, but i cant figure out how to repeat this animation set infinitly ( `android:repeatCount="infinite"` isnt working for me ).

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
android:shareInterpolator="true"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
>
<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="4.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="4.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="700"
   />
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="700"
    android:duration="2000"
    />
<rotate
    android:fromDegrees="360"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="2700"
    android:duration="2000"

    />

<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.25"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.25"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="4700"
    android:duration="700"
    />
</set>
```

and in the Activity:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
Animation rotateAndScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_z);
imageView.startAnimation(rotateAndScale);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<set>` marker in xml is bad implemented and not work propperly. Full explenation here: [Android animation does not repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480652/android-animation-does-not-repeat)

what you should do is use listener and method to use recurency to roll the anim for ever.

```
public void startAnimation() {

        View component= findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        component.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_z);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_z);
                anim.setAnimationListener(this);
                component.startAnimation(anim);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        component.startAnimation(anim);
```

}