# Android TextView Animation Infinite Repeat Not Working

Tags: android

I am trying to Animate my TextView infinitely. I have written sequential.xml which defines the animation effect as given below:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >


    <!-- Move -->
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="300"
        android:toXDelta="2%p" />

    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:startOffset="1900"
        android:toXDelta="-2%p" />

</set>
```

The Activity code which assign this animation to the TextView is as given below:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(customObject.getText());
Animation animSequential;
animSequential = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.sequential_horizontal);
animSequential.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
animSequential.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
tv.startAnimation(animSequential);
```

But it is not repeating the animation and comes to standstill at the end of first iteration. Please let me know if I have mistaken anything.

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480652/android-animation-does-not-repeat helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in the XML code. The java code did not work and I solved it well with this. Just apply this in your code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"/>

</set>
```

Add the last two lines of `<rotate>` inside your code. In your case, inside the two components `<translate>`  and remove the equivalent Java code:

```
animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
```

This code will make an object rotate on itself indefinitely, if someone serves.

Good Luck!!