# Android: animation works by code but not by xml

Tags: java, android, android-animation, android-xml

I have a very simple animation: an imageview has to go up and then down all the time. Initially I tried with xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shareInterpolator="false"
 android:fillAfter="true">
<set
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse">
    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:toYDelta="10"
        android:duration="300">
    </translate>
</set>
```

```
Animation mAnimation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation);
immagineNemico.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

But it didn't work:my imageview didn't go up, only down. So I read an answer of a question and I did the animation by code:

```
    immagineNemico.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    TranslateAnimation mAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0f,
            TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.02f);
    mAnimation.setDuration(300);
    mAnimation.setRepeatCount(-1);
    mAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    mAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    immagineNemico.setAnimation(mAnimation);
```

And it worked. But why didn't the xml animation work? They are almost the same! Where is the error?

Comment: check logs paste it here if an error occurs

Comment: @EliasFazel there aren't errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced the same issue: animations work when set by code but not in XML. The short answer is that there are bugs/intentionally confusing design in Android animations where some XML elements are ignored.

This answer to a related question is what first tipped me off that there would be things that work when done programmatically vs. via XML: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351812/8003750

I know this is not the most satisfying answer but in short - even if the XML is perfect, there are cases where it will not work.