# Android animation does not repeat

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I wanna make an animation. It has to fade in and fade out.

Works, but, I have to make it inifinite. The animation works once time.

This is my code:

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); //add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); //and this
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(1000);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    final AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); //change to false
    animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    linearLayout.setAnimation(animation);
```

I'm trying to solving like this:

[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480652/android-animation-does-not-repeat)

But is not the same case. I'm doing everything programatically.

Somebody can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Animation fadeIn , zoomout;

```
private void setAnimationOnPlayButton(){
    fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fadeIn );
    fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fadeOut );
    btnPlayVideoInPlayer.setAnimation(fadeIn);
    btnPlayVideoInPlayer.setAnimation(fadeOut);
    btnPlayVideoInPlayer.startAnimation(fadeIn);
    fadeIn .setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            btnPlayVideoInPlayer.startAnimation(zoomout);

        }
    });
    fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            btnPlayVideoInPlayer.startAnimation(fadeIn );

        }
    });
}
```

Where R.anim.fadein and R.anim.fadeout is animation file in anim folder

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this code and it works exactly how you want it to.

First of all make a new android resource directory under src>main>res called anim.

Then make a new animation resource file and call it anim_fade.xml.

Paste the following code in it.

```
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="1000" android:repeatMode="reverse"
android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
```

After you do that go to your java file and start the animation in your class. If you want it to start on app launch then paste it in your onCreate method, and if you want it to start onClick or anywhere else paste it in that class.

```
public void example{
//Major Animation code here

Animation fade = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_fade);
    linearlayout.startAnimation(fade);
}
```